# Websockets in R-Shiny

Tags: r, websocket, shiny

I'm working in Shiny, and trying to get financial data with websockets, given that latency with APIs is too large (>1min). Every minute, I need to get the open, maximum, minimum, and closing (OHLC) prices of a stream corresponding to one ticker (say, AAPL).

The code below is the skeleton of a reprex, similar to that found in the Finnhub website (https://finnhub.io/docs/api/websocket-trades).

```
library(websocket)
ws <- WebSocket$new("wss://ws.finnhub.io/?token=btj392748v6p9f1po5vg")
ws$onOpen(function(event) {
  cat("IOWebSocket opened!\n")
})
ws$onClose(function(event) {
  cat("IOWebSocket closed with code ", event$code,
      " and reason ", event$reason, "\n", sep = "")
})
ws$onError(function(event) {
  cat("IOWebSocket ERROR: ", event$message, "\n")
})
ws$onMessage(function(event) {
  cat("Received event:", event$data, "\n")
})
ws$send('{"type": "subscribe", "symbol": ["AAPL"]}')
```

Please note that the code has to run inside Shiny where, among other timing issues, (a) the connections and other functions do not immediately execute but are put in queues and (b) the script has to be prevented from simply exiting while it's doing the communication. This was noticed in https://github.com/rstudio/websocket/issues/40, which also provides some approaches to solve them.

Question

- What code has to be included to get the stream of prices, determine the OHLC values, and output the OHLC data every minute (or at selectable intervals)?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like if you add a trailing slash after the hostname, as in  `wss://ws.finnhub.io/?token=btj392748v6p9f1po5vg`, it seems to connect successfully (although it closes when you send a message, maybe due to a bad token?).

Comment: Thanks. The slash was not in the original code. I'll update the question.